# creating and instantiating instances in the heap memory

Tags: c++, heap-memory

What am i missing here

```
class A{
   private :
      string Name;
      int seatNo;
   public :
      void setName(string n){
         Name=n;
      }

      void setNumber(int number){
         seatNo=number;
      }
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
   A *a1=new A[10]();

   *a1[0].setName("Name1");
   return 0;
}
```

I'm always getting this error 
<kbd>error: void value not ignored as it ought to be</kbd>

Comment: remove `*` from `*a1[0].setName("Name1")` and don't forget to `delete[] a1;`

Comment: I've tried this 3 times before asking , and when you suggested it , it worked!

Comment: You're trying to dereference a1 twice, which is not possible since it's just a single-level pointer.